# Surjectivity of the exponential map on SO(2n)/U(n)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, compact-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

Let $M:=SO(2n)/U(n)$ the homogeneous space of all orthogonal almost-complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

When $n=2$, it is known that $M$ is just the 2-sphere.

1) On the 2-sphere, the exponential map at any point is surjective, is that true?

2) If yes, is this fact true for all $n$ ?  In other words, is it true that for all $n$, the exponential map at any point of $M$ is surjective onto $M$ ?

Comment: Geodesically complete spaces have surjective exponential maps, and compact manifolds are automatically complete.

Comment: From what I know, geodesically complete means that we can define the exponential map on the whole tangent space. Does this implies surjectivity?

Comment: Google Hopf-Rinow theorem.